# CSS3 save position after animation

Tags: css

i have a banner that move when i pass the mouse over it, and when the mouse exit, the banner go back to it's original position, i want to know how to make it stop at it's current position after animation (i don't want to reset each time )

this is how it moves :

```
  /*keyframe animations*/
.first:hover {
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
       -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
         -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
            animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}


@-webkit-keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
   margin-left: 0px;
 }
 100% {
   margin-left: -2125px;
 }

}
```

Comment: It changes because in your key frame its 0% 0px and 100% 2125px. And in your animation CSS your have the iteration count to infinite so its going to constantly repeat 0px to 2125px

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things to think about:

- You will likely need to hover another element like a containing div, its hard to continue to hover over an element when it goes off screen.
- Add an [animation fill mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode), this will persist the end state of the animation for as long as the user continues to hover.

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/fjQ2E/1/)**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
</div>

 .container:hover .first{
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -2125px;
    }
}
```

If you need the animation end state to persist after the user isn't hovering anymore you may want to consider using a little script to add the animation by adding a class, like so:

[**Working Example 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/fjQ2E/2/)

```
$('.first').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.first').addClass('banner');
});

.banner{
    -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
    animation: bannermove 30s linear both;
}
```

If you should need to have the animation pause when the user is no longer hovering and resume when hovered again:

**[Working Example 3](http://jsfiddle.net/fjQ2E/3/)**

```
$('.first').hover(function () {
    $('.first').addClass('banner');
    $('.banner').css('animationPlayState', 'running');
},

function () {
    $('.banner').css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
});
```

Comment: Nicely done apaul. Wish I could do more help though only have a phone at the moment. Anyways I wonder if op wants the element to stay at position that its at once we mouseout like if its margin-left:250px at the current frame of leaving the element and stay at 250px or whatever.

Comment: Good job. I like it when users give more than one option. Now is the animationPlayState cross browser ? See that's why I like doing more advanced animations with vanilla just a taste of my own I won't depend much on css3 until its 100% cross browser

Comment: @EasyBB pretty sure that all browsers that support css animations also support animation-play-state, some need prefixes though see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state

Answer (score -1):

```
  .first:hover {
   -webkit-animation: bannermove 30s linear ;
   -moz-animation: bannermove 30s linear ;
    -ms-animation: bannermove 30s linear ;
     -o-animation: bannermove 30s linear ;
        animation: bannermove 30s linear 
   }
```

by placing infinite you set the iteration count to constantly play back repetitively. Taking out infinite will solve your issue.

Comment: it still give me the same effect :/

Comment: Do you want the element to stay at the exact location where it was when your mouse exited the banner? If so we would probably need JavaScript for that. If not are you just wanting the element to move while your mouse is over and stay at -2125px?

Comment: "Do you want the element to stay at the exact location where it was when your mouse exited the banner?"
Yes exactly

Comment: See apauls revised answer below as I'm on my phone so I can't write much lol. I've already upvoted his answer and his seems like the logical answer that you need.